# Taking input from the python interpreter and writing it to file

Tags: python, input, output

The user will enter data in the python interpreter in the following format :-

```
Chapters 
TRAN~Transfiguration~1~2011-2012~Instructor1
CHAR~Charms~1~2011-2012~Instructor2
Students
001~Hannah Abbott
002~Euan Abercrombie
003~Stewart Ackerley
004~Bertram Aubrey
005~Avery
006~Malcolm Baddock
007~Marcus Belby
008~Katie Bell
009~Sirius Orion Black
Grades
subject1~1~2011-2012~SLY2301~AB
subject2~2011-2012~SLY2302~B
TRAN~1~2011-2012~SLY2303~B
TRAN~1~2011-2012~SLY2305~A
```

and the data has to be written to a file for further processing . How to do this in Python ?

Comment: Have you looked at the `input()` function for taking input? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input Also look at the `open.write` function for writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
entry = "Anything";

with open("file.txt", 'w') as f:
    while entry != "Done":
        entry = input("Enter here: ");
        f.writelines(entry+"\n");
```

Hope this helps.

**P.S:** Try to provide some attempts that you've made towards solving the issue or problem. That would encourage people to help you.

Comment: You don't need semicolons on the end of those lines, by the way. This isn't JavaScript :)

Comment: Yeah @numbermaniac. I keep as a matter of practice from my C background. It also avoids my end of line/syntax confusion ^_^

Comment: I used the above code but what ii'm getting is syntax error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\readafile.py", line 5, in <module>
    entry = input("Enter here: ");
  File "<string>", line 2
    TRAN~Transfiguration~1~2011-2012~Instructor1
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @kroy: Which version of python you're running. This would work in python versions 3.0 and above

Comment: @RussellB Thanks .!! I  m pretty new to Python and was using python 2.7 . it worked after installing python 3 .

Comment: @kroy If you find the answer acceptable, please do accept for others to use that. :)